# Syscall mremap() does not work as I expected. Is it bugged, is there any other way of remaping memory?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

My example uses non-POSIX `mremap()` call to connect chunks of anonymous memory allocated with `mmap()` into a one continues region. Based on the available [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) I expected this to work properly. However `mremap()` operation 'grow' unexpectedly fails, most likely due to in-kernel representation (known as VM/VMA) of memory chunk, where one continuous userspace region is still two separate VM/VMA inside a kernel.

Algorithm is as follows:

1. Having memory A and B, grow A to (A+B) size (move of A may happens)
2. Move B to a newly added space at the end of A
3. Having also C memory, grow A to (A + B + C) size (This step fails: `EFAULT 14 Bad address`)
4. Move C to a newly added space at the end of A

Exact code is available on [github](https://github.com/MaciejPolanski/v_mremap/blob/c1b4b567ce3be1ba84bd423814aa5bafb13026a0/mremap_test.c).

Since 'grow' call works the first time, but doesn't work at the second time, I conclude that problem in second call is that memory is constructed from two separate in-kernel regions so `mremap` cannot handle such parameter.

Such diagnosis may have some support in the kernel comments, however I am not sure how to interpret `mm/mremap.c: mremap_to()`:

```
        /* We can't remap across vm area boundaries */
        if (old_len > vma->vm_end - addr)
                return ERR_PTR(-EFAULT);
```

On the other hand, there is no such requirement in the documentation, and it would be surprising to make the user space call dependent on an internal kernel representation.

We may also read in documentation https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html:

```
EFAULT Some address in the range old_address to
       old_address+old_size is an invalid virtual memory address
       for this process.  You can also get EFAULT even if there
       exist mappings that cover the whole address space
       requested, but those mappings are of different types.
```

Use of plural 'mappings' clearly suggests that it should be possible to use an area composed of multiple mappings (provided types are the same).

So can someone help me on this:

- Is `mremap()` bugged or I am using it incorrectly?
- Or maybe this is a call that "does what author needed it for" and my expectations are unrealistic?
- Is there any other way of remapping arbitrary memory in userspace?

Comment: You can't combine two regions that use different page fault handlers.  What would you do on a page fault?  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.18/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L390

Comment: But why would two anonymous private memory regions have different handlers?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the interesting part of your code:

```
// This test attaches new mapped memory to 'a' chunk.
// However, it fails at second time for unclear reason.
// First, let's create initial mmapped region 'a'
void* a = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE, /*not a file mapping*/-1, 0);
err(a, 1);

// Creation of 'b' and attaching it at the end of 'a'
// 'a' need to be enlarged first, relocation is possible
void* b = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE, /*not a file mapping*/-1, 0);
err(b, 2);    
a = mremap(a, size, 2 * size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);                      // Grow 'a'
err(a, 3);
b = mremap(b, size, size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, a + size); // Attach 'b' at the end
err(b, 4);
```

At this point you have two 4K mappings, 'a' is immediately followed by 'b'. Putting 'b' where you did overwrote part of 'a' shrinking it to 4K.

```
// Creation of 'c' and attaching it at the end of 'a'
// 'a' need to be enlarged first, relocation is possible
void* c = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE, /*not a file mapping*/-1, 0);
err(c, 5);    
a = mremap(a, 2 * size, 3 * size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);                   // <- this fails: EFAULT 14 Bad address
```

This fails because 'a' is only 4k, not 8K. Making this change works:

```
a = mremap(a, size, 3 * size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
```

Comment: But if 'a' is relocated, which is allowed to make room at the end, it will not copy 'b' to new location. 
So any memory management based on such memory mapping has to store information on all sub-areas and move it one by one?

Comment: There are no sub areas. a and b are independent mappings, each 4k. You are trying to remap across a boundary.

Comment: Yes, as there is no such requirement in documentation, and even it is suggested - as described in original question - that is is officially possible. 
So I made a huge amount of code - not this example - that depends on it and it does not work. And will not work, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the new mapping, this is what happens:

```
   ┌───┐
0. │ A │                 Existing mapping.
   └───┘
   ┌───┐         ┌───┐
1. │ A │     ... │ B │   Create new mapping.
   └───┘         └───┘
   ┌───────┐     ┌───┐
2. │ A   _ │ ... │ B │   Extend original mapping address range.
   └───────┘     └───┘
   ┌───┬───┐
3. │ A │ B │             Move new mapping over extended address range.
   └───┴───┘
   ┌───┬───┐     ┌───┐
4. │ A │ B │ ... │ C │   Create new mapping.
   └───┴───┘     └───┘
   ┌───┬───┐     ┌───┐
5. │ A │ B │ ... │ C │   Cannot extend mapping A, because B is in the way.
   └───┴───┘     └───┘
```

I.e., even though you do have the correct mappings in continuous addresses, by moving B on top of A you do not "merge" the mappings, you only move them.  They stay as separate mappings.

If you read the kernel pseudofile `/proc/self/maps`, you'll see that your mapping region is indeed split into multiple mappings.  I am not aware of any way for userspace to ask the kernel to coalesce different mappings to a single one, aside from just doing a `mmap(...MAP_FIXED...)` over the entire region, but that will clear the existing contents to zero.

You can try growing only the final mapping in the region (`B` in step 5. above), but only with zero flags (without `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` or `MREMAP_FIXED`).  If that fails, then you need to do a `mmap(NULL, total_grown_length, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0)` to obtain a completely new virtual address range you can mremap() each and every one of the mappings you do have, one by one. (Note that that mmap() call does not reserve RAM, only address space.) If that also fails, well, there just isn't enough virtual address space left anymore.

If the new mappings are anonymous memory, then the obvious solution is to just use `memcpy()` to *copy* the data from the separate mapping, and then unmap that new mapping.  Or better yet, just extend the original mapping in the first place, and use the extended area.

Comment: Big picture is that I wanted avoid paying for soft faults and zeroing newly mmap'ed memory.  By reusing old unused chunks. So "make a new mmap" is not a solution.
Building one by one inside empty mmap'ed region could work. However, as time goes on, memory becomes more and more fragmented and the number of VMs is limited, so everything inevitably heads for disaster. And complications of my memory structures is skyrocketing.
Do you not happen to know why in case 3 B is not included in A? That would be a more logical way out, there would then be both VM divide and merge operations.

Comment: @MaciejPolański: I do not see how you can avoid paying for soft faults after changing mappings; don't forget all that kernel has to invalidate the affected areas anyway; cache in particular.  As to the step 3, why B is not included in A, is that they are independent mappings; there just hasn't been a valid use case to **swap the backing** between two mappings (old extended A and B), which is basically what you're trying to do (followed by unmapping B, being unused extended A at this point). [...]

Comment: @MaciejPolański: [...] The kernel does have [vma_merge()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/vma_merge), but I don't see how it would help here.  Are you **sure** you're limited by soft page faults and not by cache-memory bandwidth?  In HPC, the key is to ensure cache locality and compact access patterns in cacheline granular units (that is, put as much related stuff that always gets accessed together in the same cacheline as you can fit, and avoid accessing any cacheline for just one field), and for larger amounts of data, in *linear* contiguous chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts BTW. At very start of my study is that usage of big chunks of memory allocated with  mmap(…MAP_POPULATE…) is noticeably faster than allocated without prepopulation. I need to digest all this more :)